# what data structure to use for multidimensional mesh grid? (c++)

Tags: c++, testing, data-structures

I need to code a test platform for testing a specific algorithm. The system is supposed to be definable by input and 3 dimensional - similar to network on chip it has both node and link elements connecting to connect them. Due to the dimensions and links between nodes i have had some hardships on figuring out what data structures to use - a 3 dimensional array like array[x][y][z] is hard to handle as the pointer with drawbacks when adding links to connect the nodes (leaves several null value holes in the structure). Binary search trees are hard to realize since its a grid type. For this reason i have thought about doing a linked list where links are easier to implement.
(the final testing platform should look something like the presentation below) where every link is also mapped down as they contain communication schedules

```
01-------02-------03
| \      | \      | \
|  10----|--11----|--12
|  | \   |  | \   |  | \
|  |  19-|--|--20-|--|--21
04-------05-------06 |  |
| \   |  | \|  |  | \|  |
|  13----|--14----|--15 |
|  | \|  |  | \|  |  | \|
|  |  22-|--|--23-|--|--24
07-------08-------09 |  |
  \|  |    \|  |    \|  |
   16-------17-------18 |
     \|       \|       \|
      25-------26-------27
```

Can any of you offer some help as to what type of structure in c++ would suit this kind of task. The finished program should be able to generate such a structure, given the dimension parameters of x, y and z.

currently a the rough outline should look like this

```
>class Node{
>  public:
>   Link* north;
>   Link* east;
>   Link* south;
>   Link* west;
>   Link* up;
>   Link* down;
>   //will contain a node specific scheduler
>}
>
>class Link{
>
>   Node* A;
>   Node* B;
>   //will contain a link specific scheduler
>}
```

EDIT 22.01.2013

well first of all as its a testing platform simulating a three dimensional network on chip type multiprocessor system. The task this system has to fill is to enable testing certain algorithms to help map tasks onto these nodes (where each node is connected to a processor core). In the light of this, the memory consumption might not be a problem as it is only for testing as i stated, for this reason it is imperative that the system would have both nodes and links as neither of them can be used by two event at the same time (communication on a link will block all other communications etc, this is the reason why i wrote that the class type node/link will have a scheduler in it)

Comment: Kudos on the nice cube :) How big is the cube? When it comes to these kinds of things it's usually weighting pros and cons of the different alternatives. If it's just 3x3x3 I'd probably have gone with an array, arr[x][y][z]

Comment: @dutt Why only if it's 3x3x3? arr[x][y][z] seems like a good answer regardless of size, as long as it's a non-sparse tree. Unless maybe it's so big you can't find enough contiguous memory to allocate it.

Comment: Do all links between nodes necessarily exist? If not, and if you have multiple disconnected subnetworks, your linked "list" loses positioning information. Not sure if that matters for your application, but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: @Dave I was thinking of enough memory, but sparseness is an even better point.

Comment: It really depends on the connectivity of the graph.

Answer (score 11):

It depends very much on **what kind of operations** you are going to perform on that structure. Will you have to do *searches*? If so, what kind: value-based or position-based? Will you have to perform *transformations* on it? Will you have to access all of its elements repeatedly and in a sequence? Will you have to access elements based on their *position* in the grid? Is your structure *sparse* or *dense*?

Moreover, do you want to minimize *creation* time, *search* time, *navigation* time, or *transformation* time? This all gives fundamental information to make a decision.

I would **not** go for a solution based on nodes and links, because it is:

1. expensive in terms of *memory consumption* (due to the extra link pointers);
2. expensive in terms of *complexity* (navigating all the nodes require following
   all the links, so no random access), and;
3. expensive in terms of *data locality* (nodes will be allocated individually and spread all over
   the heap at separate addresses, which will generate many cache misses and slow down your program);
4. *error-prone* (messing up with links is easy, especially if you use raw pointers and don't want to pay for smart pointers' memory overhead)

Without knowing too much about your requirements, I would probably suggest you having a look at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

If you want to do things on your own, then (again, without knowing too much about your requirements) I would suggest you using a `vector<vector<vector<double>>>`, which is relatively simple, does not have fixed size and allows you resizing at run-time, guarantees you O(1) access through the subscripting operator and also *some* locality of the data (you have several vectors here, so as long as you access data from *one* vector performance will be fine).

A plain C-style multi-dimensional array is also a possibility, but it's inherently unsafe, which would make it a last-resort choice if I were you (also, allocating a contiguous block of memory might be impossible if your structure is huge).